# Opening the top-level module applied on arguments

Tags: module, agda

I'd like to put the definition of a top-level Agda module and a local anonymous module using it in the same file. However, the top-level module has parameters, and I'd like to instantiate it in the second module.

So basically I would like to do something like this:

```
module MyModule (A : Set) where

foo : A -> A
foo x = x

module _ where
  open import Data.Bool
  open MyModule Bool
  
  bar = foo true
```

However, the `open MyModule Bool` line fails with "The module `MyModule` is not parameterized, but is being applied to arguments".

Is there a way to do this without:

- putting the second module in a separate file
- indenting the contents of `MyModule`, i.e. something like

  ```
  module _ where

  module MyModule (A : Set) where
    foo : A -> A
    foo x = x

  module _ where
    open import Data.Bool
    open MyModule Bool

    bar = foo true
  ```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The precise thing you're asking for is currently not possible in Agda. The closest thing I can think of is the following:

```
module MyModule where

module Main (A : Set) where

  foo : A -> A
  foo x = x

private
  module _ where
    open import Data.Bool
    open Main Bool

    bar = foo true

open Main public
```

This will expose the contents of the main module in their generic form while hiding the private definition `bar` from other modules. However, when you import the module and want to instantiate the parameter, you cannot write `open import MyModule Nat` directly, you'd have to instead write

```
import MyModule using (module Main)
open MyModule.Main Nat
```

(for importing the generic version, `open import MyModule` would work just fine).